# Meteor cursor.fetch().property returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, meteor, settimeout, fetch

I have a simple helper that returns an array to an #each block inside my template. This works ok and the tags are displaying.

However, i don't understand why i can't console.log a property of the userTags, for instance userTags.BusinessContact. But i can console.log the complete object so (console.log(userTags)) will work.

```
    Template.profileTags.helpers({

        tag:function(){

            var userTags = tikiUser.find({}).fetch()

            //this returns "undefined" 2 times
            Meteor.setTimeout(function(){console.log(userTags.BusinessContact)}, 500)

            return userTags

        }

    })
```

Why is that?

thx,

Comment: Have you published and subscribe the table before fetching..??

Comment: do you have subscription for `tikiUser` collection ?

Comment: Yes, at the top of the file: Meteor.subscribe("tikiUser")

Comment: @kevinius dO not put the subscription anywhere like top file. Always load the subscription first then template. Anyways, Put the subscriptions inside `Meteor.startup()` or If you are using the Iron Router try put the subscriptions in `subscription` property or on `waitOn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the BusinessContact property of an array - try doing

```
 userTags[0].BusinessContact
```

PS: Try to make a meteorpad.com when posting a problem

Comment: you're welcome :) 
Perhaps you can use findOne().BusinessContact

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
if(userTags)
 {
   Console.log(userTags.BusinessContact)
    }
```

In meteor some time we will not get value for the first time so,If we write a **if** condition than it will check the value there Only.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have set up everything correct because if i just console.log(userTags) i get all the properties of the returned cursor data. It's when i do a console log of a property (userTags.BusinessContact) that i get "undefined" 2 times

Comment: can you just give your cursor data that you are getting from database

Comment: Yes, here it is: (i get this when i do console.log(userTags){

                    userName:"Liselore Dekempe",
                    userAge:33,
                    userSex:"female",
                    BusinessName:"Umono Comm. v.",
                    BusinessAddress:"Descampsstraat 16, 8370 Blankenberge",
                    BusinessContact:"Kevin Vanhove",
                    BusinessEmail:"kevinvanhove@gmail.com",
                    BusinessVAT:"123 456 789",
                    BusinessPhone:"0495/92 97 46",
                   
                }